# Using a #define substitution to standardized return arguments and function arguments

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am going to have many functions with the same signatures (return argument and function parameters) and these parameters are long and may change over time. But I will have potentially hundreds of these functions and I thought it would convenient to use a `#define` macro to state what the arguments should be so that I only have to change them in one place, like so:

`#define ARGS const Object& ref, float x, float y`

`#define RET QVector<Object>`

Such that I could use it like this:

`RET func1(ARGS); //extern header declaration`

But using `#define` like this doesn't compile. Is there a trick to getting `#define` to do this, or is it simply not possible?

Comment: That would make for some really ugly and confusing code.  I'd prefer to use a typedef for the return value and pass the params in a struct.

Comment: @RetiredNinja valid option, but this is performance sensitive code to be run hundreds of times per second and I want to avoid the overhead of creating a struct object for passing

Comment: What error do you get? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @rici I'm using Qt with C++ so maybe I should remove the C tag. In any case, I get odd errors about "return type not specified" and "syntax error"

Comment: Did you include the headers that define the `QVector` template and `Object` before you use the macros?  If not, that'll account for the errors you see.  If you did, you probably need to produce an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) that reproduces your problem.  You can use a simple surrogate class for `Object` and a simple template for `QVector` so that you don't need any external headers in the compilation.  You can then also show the preprocessed source.  OTOH, by then it is likely to be obvious what your problem is.

Comment: I'll also observe that if you ever have to change the arguments to the hundreds of functions (e.g. add an extra argument for the third dimension: `float z`), you're also going to have to make appropriate changes to the bodies of the hundreds of functions to make use of the extra arguments appropriately.  Are you sure you shouldn't be using templates for the functions anyway?  Preprocessor hacks tend to be very nasty.  I'd not like to work with your code if it used these macros.  (However, they should work OK if you decide to go ahead anyway.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well there is nothing wrong with adding a new argument to a function but not using that argument; obviously the main problem is to remove an argument that a function is in fact using

Comment: Agreed, though why add the argument if it is not meant to be used? The main point is that you can't simply change the arguments at will by this mechanism.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler if I introduce a new function that needs an argument the others didn't but I need all functions to have same signature (because I am using function pointers to them), I could do it this way.

Comment: -1. "I want to avoid the overhead of creating a struct object" without checking if there's actually such an overhead. Modern compilers can already pass structs in registers. This just uglifies what compilers already do.

Comment: @MSalters Well I am passing the arguments between threads in Qt so they will always be copied. Here I'd be creating a struct and then it gets copied during the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose all of your functions accept two `float` arguments and return an `int`, you can have:

```
#define FUN(name) int (name)(float x, float y)

FUN(func1)
{
   std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;
   return 1;
}

FUN(func2)
{
   std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;
   return 2;
}

// use of functions
// func1(1.0, 1.0);
// func2(2.0, 2.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define RET void
#define ARGS (int a,int b)

RET func ARGS;

int main()
{

func(10,20);

}
RET func ARGS
{
printf("a and b is %d and %d",a,b);
return;

}
```

This is what you want?
This works for me.